# Ver detalles Mongodb en Debian

Tags: mongodb, shell, debian, terminal

Me hace falta una forma de ver la `bd`, colecciones y documentos de `MongoDb`. Ya que suelo comunicarme con mongo utilizando `mongoose`.

Quisiera saber una forma directa desde la consola de acceder a la características de una `bd` que ya haya creado. Con características me refiero a como esta estructurado determinada colección de objetos, los campos, validadores, etc, que lo conforman así como sus documentos.

Hasta ahora se que si escribo `mongo` me sale un `shell` que me permite interactuar con `mongodb`, pero me falta un poco de experiencia con esto. Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB – comandos básicos

Ahora si primero vamos a entrar a nuestra terminal de linux o windows y accesamos a la consola de mongo, una vez que entramos desde nuestra terminal vamos a usar el comando:
`show dbs;`
este comando nos muestra las bases de datos que tenemos en mongodb:
`use [nombre de la base];`
con este comando hacemos uso de una base de datos, tambien este comando nos crea una base de datos y aparecera listada con
`show dbs`;
hasta que insertemos un documento en la coleccion.
`db.[coleccion].insert(   [documento en formato JSON]  ) ;`
Para insertar y crear una coleccion de datos en MongoDB solo debemos usar la sentencia `insert` y agregar el documento (datos) en formato JSON, la colecciones se crean automaticamente en mongodb una vez que insertamos un elemento o coleccion.
`show collections;`
Este comando nos muestra las colecciones disponibles en la base datos, recuerda primero seleccionar la base de datos con el comando `use`.
`db.[coleccion].find();`
el comando `find()` nos muestra la lista de documentos (“registros”) de una coleccion, podemos filtrar o enviar  al comando find para especificar los resultados de nuestra consulta.
`db.[coleccion].find().pretty();`
si deseamos que los resultados se vean mucho mejor o darle un salida mas visible en pantalla, solo debemos agregar a la consulta   pretty() que hara que el resultado se vea bonito!

Para mas información acerca de la notación JSON puedes usar este link http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp, puedes encontrar la documentación de mongodb en este link para ver a profundidad los comandos aqui mostrados https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

Answer (score 0):

Este enlace sobre comandos básicos de la shell de Mongo (i.e. a lo que accedes cuando tecleas `mongo`) te puede ser de utilidad:

https://jarriagadeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/01/19/mongodb-comandos-basicos/

Comment: Bienvenido @fgalan te recomiendo que edites la respuesta agregando la información que sirva como respuesta, normalmente las respuestas que solo ofrecen enlaces son rechazadas por la comunidad

Comment: Exacto, vi el link, y sirve, pero creo que seria mas apropiado si hicieras tu aporte en SO escribiendo la respuesta.

Comment: Podría hacer así... pero dudo que lo hiciera mejor que Javier Arriaga ni tampoco quiero plaguiarle copi-pegando ;) Si la comunidad estima que mi respuesta basada en link no es apropiada, que lo exprese con downvotes y yo mismo borraré mi post cuando esté en -3, moviendo el link a un comentario en el question post.

Comment: @fgalan puedes ver sobre el tema aqui https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2168/normas-a-la-hora-de-sugerir-fuentes-de-informaci%C3%B3n-en-internet

Comment: El link es util, pero no tienes que plagearle, puedes explicar lo que pone el link, y asi ayudar a la comunidad aunque sea brevemente.